# Update void doesnt work for me, what am I missing?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making an app for a school project, and am working with showing/hiding images to make an 'upgrade' and 'downgrade' button. I have made it so when you press a button, it updates the image. At first I had this with structuring my code differently. The issue with that was the fact it wouldnt load my current picture state in again after I left and re-entered the scene (although it would save the value of the upgradelevel). When I tried to restructure it, nothing works. What am I doing wrong here (if it can even be done like this...)?

I had structured the code differently at first, but came to the issue of my image not loading when I re-entered the scene. Structuring the code like this I felt it would bypass that issue. Now another issue has come up.

```
public GameObject woodWeapon;
public GameObject stoneWeapon;
public GameObject metalWeapon;
public static int weaponLevel = 0;

public void upgradeWeapon()
{
    weaponLevel += 1;

    if (weaponLevel > 3)
    {
        weaponLevel = 3;
    }
}
public void downgradeWeapon()
{
    weaponLevel -= 1;

    if (weaponLevel < 0)
    {
        weaponLevel = 0;
    }
}
public void Update()
{

    if (weaponLevel == 0)
    {
        woodWeapon.SetActive(false);
        stoneWeapon.SetActive(false);
        metalWeapon.SetActive(false);
    }
    else if (weaponLevel == 1)
    {
        woodWeapon.SetActive(true);
        stoneWeapon.SetActive(false);
        metalWeapon.SetActive(false);
    }
    else if (weaponLevel == 2)
    {
        woodWeapon.SetActive(false);
        stoneWeapon.SetActive(true);
        metalWeapon.SetActive(false);
    }
    else if (weaponLevel == 3)
    {
        woodWeapon.SetActive(false);
        stoneWeapon.SetActive(false);
        metalWeapon.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

Expected result: Pressing 'upgrade' button updates my screen with am image, a wood sword instead of nothing, a stone sword instead of a wood sword, etc...
pressing 'downgrade' should do the same thing, but the other way around

Reality: Pressing either 'upgrade' or 'downgrade' does nothing to the image.

Comment: Add some debug messages, why would you set/unset the weapon every frame?

Comment: @BugFinder There are no bug messages. And put the weapon setting/upsetting in the update screen as I am not aware of a way to only update it every time I get into a scene. Is there a way to do this? If so, that fixes about all my issues im pretty sure now that I think of it.

Comment: How did you wire the button events to the methods, are they even called? Is your class a MonoBehaviour or do you have more inheritance in place? Is there a reason for weaponLevel to be static?

Comment: Update will not be called if the script/gameobject is disabled, probably that's why it isn't working. BTW, you can just store a `SpriteRenderer` and change its `sprite`. No need to have 3 objects which you set active and inactive.

Comment: @trollingchar Ill give that a shot, never heard of a spriterenderer sooo :3"

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @ReinierJongerius `SpriteRenderer` is a component that sprites have. But if you have UI elements, there is an `Image` component and you should use it instead.

Comment: @ReinierJongerius no you need to ADD them, put in debug messages to see where things get to what values you have.. eg normal debugging techniques